# How can I receive cookie in layout page in asp.net core razorpage?

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, razor-pages

I create login page in the asp.net core RazorPage and the code below is:
Login page:

```
 List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim("Test","Test"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier as string,user.UserID.ToString()  as string),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,user.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role as string,user.UserRole.ToString() as string)
            };

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            var claimPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            HttpContext.SignInAsync(claimPrincipal);
            return RedirectToPage("../Index");
```

and my _layout page is like this
_Layout:

```
                if (???????????)
                    {
                        <div>@User.Identity.Name</div>
                        <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex justify-content-end">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-page="/Auth/Logout">Logout</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex justify-content-end flex-grow-1">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-page="/Auth/login">Login</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="btn" asp-page="/Auth/Register">Register</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    }
```

the question is:
What should I put instead of question marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determine whether the user has successfully logged in,

Try below code in _layout:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
```

In my startup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie();
```

result:

[image]

Comment: it not work without any error.
when i login with an account in my explorer in the Storage Make two Cookies 1)anti forgery token and 2)Identity_External

Comment: @PilotReza What is your Identity_External ? Can you share your startup.cs?